# R NameSpaces beyond packages

Tags: r, namespaces

I am working on a R project that which requred me to write quite a lot functions, some are specific to just one part of the project. 
When I used work in other languages Namespaces helped me keep my functions organized within a project/package not just between packges. Right now I have more functions clutering my `.GlobalEnv` than I can/want to keep track of.

For some reason I can't find documentation on using namespaces in R other than about how NAMESPACE file is used to export functions, and in offical R documentation namespace functions are doucumented  as internal functions (which does not make me confident that I  should be calling them myself).

So my question is: Are namespaces ONYL intended to shield package functions from being overwritten by other packages?

I am not asking about your individual opinion I'm sure that you can hack you way into using any functionality in an unintended way(as base R devs envisioned it). I am asking about what is the inteded use of namespaces.

In event that I missed something I'm happy to do more reaserch, so could you provide links to useful materials I may have missed?

Comment: You haven't missed anything. R doesn't have general purpose namespacing like other languages. They are only used in the context of packages and controlling the search path. Some info is in the R language definition (but not much): https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#index-namespace

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for prompt response, I must say I'm disapointed that such feature is missing.